# How to pass to from_json a dynamic json schema stored in a column

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark

I have this dataframe schema:

```
root
 |-- data: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- schema: string (nullable = false)
```

and the dataframe looks like this:

| data | schema |
| --- | --- |
| [{"APN":"Test1","DeviceIPAddress":"Test2"}, {"APN":"Test3","DeviceIPAddress":"Test4"}] | STRUCT<APN: STRING, DeviceIPAddress: STRING |

Basically this dataframe is composed by a column that is an array of json string and another column that is the corresponding schema.

I want to explode the rows, of each element of the list that will have the same schema.
I want to get this result:

| APN | DeviceIpAddress |
| --- | --- |
| Test1 | Test2 |
| Test3 | Test4 |

If I fix the schema and pass it as string to from_json function it works, but I want it is dynamic.

This is the code I'm using with the relative error:

```
df.withColumn("jsonData", explode("data"))\
        .withColumn("jsonData", from_json(col("jsonData"), col("schema")))\
        .withColumn("jsonData", explode(array("jsonData")))\
        .select("jsonData.*")
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Schema should be specified in DDL format as a string literal or output of the schema_of_json/schema_of_csv functions instead of "schema"

Basically the error happens when I pass the col("schema") to the from_json function. If I create it as static, and I pass it as variable it works. Is there a way to pass to schema of from_json function the schema I have in the column?

Comment: have you tried using it within `expr()`?

Comment: yes @samkart and it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Try by using `expr()` and use `from_json()` function by passing `column names` here

**`Example:`**

```
df.withColumn("jsonData", explode("data"))\
        .withColumn("jsonData", expr('from_json(jsonData,schema)'))\
        .withColumn("jsonData", explode(array("jsonData")))\
        .select("jsonData.*")
```

Comment: I tried but unfortunately I get the same error